# How can I construct canonical resource for Azure Storage Table Set Table Service Properties endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-table-storage

Azure exposes an endpoint to [set table service properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452240.aspx). This endpoint expects client to pass `Authorization` header and that could be formatted as `SharedKeyLite <account-name>:<signature>` for Table services as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx). `signature` is the sha256 encoded form of `<date>\n<canonical-resource>` for which canonical resource construction follows the rules:

> 1. Beginning with an empty string (""), append a forward slash (/), followed by the name of the account that owns the resource being
>      accessed.
> 2. Append the resource's encoded URI path. If the request URI addresses a component of the resource, append the appropriate query
>      string. The query string should include the question mark and the comp
>      parameter (for example, ?comp=metadata). No other parameters should be
>      included on the query string.

according to [Authentication documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx).

I am able to authenticate for [query tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179471.aspx) or [entity operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179375.aspx). However, **I am consistently failing to authenticate for set table service properties endpoint.** I construct canonical resource by starting with `"/<account-name>"` according to **rule 1** and then I append another `"/"` without any query string, because I believe request URI (which is `https://<account-name>.table.core.windows.net/?restype=service&comp=properties`) is not addressing a component according to **rule 2**. That makes canonical resource `"/<account-name>/"`.

Is there anybody managed to authenticate for this endpoint at all? If so how?

NOTE 1: I tried otherwise (appended query string too and that made the canonical resource `"/<account-name>/?comp=properties"`), but failed again.

NOTE 2: **Rule 2** asks to append encoded URI path, but that is not really the case.

Comment: Can you share your code please? I can take a look.

Comment: You may be able to use our existing libs or at least copy or port the auth code from them. Ex: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/table/internal/sharedkeytable.js

Comment: @emilygernermicrosoft I looked at the code. The canonical resource format as `"/<account-name>/?comp=properties"` should work, but it does not. However, that library uses content type `application/xml;charset="utf-8"` whereas I use `application/xml` according to [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535600.aspx). I'll try with that content-type, I doubt it is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to partially resolve the issue. The problem is Azure storage emulator behaves different than the actual storage service. [Set Table Service Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452240.aspx) endpoint is not authenticating the request on the emulator whereas it goes through fine on the service itself. Other requests against table (read, create, delete) and entities (create, read, update and delete) are behaving same on emulator and service.

The canonical resource is formatted as `"/<account-name>/?comp=properties"`. Content type makes no difference in authentication as expected.